# Bootstrap таблица со скроллингом данных и фиксированным thead

Tags: bootstrap, javascript, html, css

Вроде нашёл много примеров, как сделать таблицу со скроллингом данных и фиксированным заголовком. Но всё что-то не так или глючит. Подскажите правильное решение?

Comment: Вы бы хоть пример какой добавили, что ли, что в вашем представлении является правильным решением.

Comment: Ну, например, www.fixedheadertable.com . Но, вроде, не под Bootstrap... Лучше покажу неправильное решение: http://www.bootply.com/ihUoTIsnt5 - если разной длины ячейки, то всё смешается.

Comment: Попытался сам слабать, вот какой результат получился: http://www.bootply.com/xZTDMIvY4l Как Вам?